# The provider is not compatible with this version of oracle client. ASP.net and oracle issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle-client

I have been having an issue with trying to get Oracle client to work on my VS project. The Exception I keep on getting is:

```
    The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand' threw an exception'
```

also the inner exception is:

```
    The provider is not compatible with this version of oracle client'
```

I did look at my web.conf and saw I had version 4.0.0.0 within the assemblies and I am targeting to .NET 4.0 with a 64-bit machine. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Oracle data provider require Oracle Client installed on your machine.